# How to convert SVG to TopoJSON

Tags: javascript, dictionary, d3.js, svg, topojson

I'm working on a project using d3.js. I need to convert an SVG file in TopoJSON format in order to display the map. How do I do this? I have tried using mygeodata.cloud, but it requires a subscription which I can't afford or justify. Is there a way to convert it another way?

Comment: Why not just display the SVG? Why do you need to convert it to a different vector format?

Comment: Because I can't get d3.zoom to work with SVG

Comment: It'll probably be easier to apply d3.zoom to the SVG than to extract the coordinates (and unproject them if overlaying other features). After all, topojson and geojson usually are drawn as SVG. However, if conversion to a different vector format is needed, it will be easier to convert those coordinates to geojson as opposed to topojson (geojson doesn't encode coordinates like topojson). Can you share the SVG?

Comment: I've made a map using a topoJSON that diplays regions of Croatia. After a certain zoom, I want to display another map that displays municipalities of Croatia.
Here is the map of the regions: https://www.dropbox.com/s/17o44aerf71zfwg/hr.svg?dl=0
Here is the topoJSON file for the regions: https://www.dropbox.com/s/17o44aerf71zfwg/hr.svg?dl=0
And here is the SVG for municipalities: https://www.dropbox.com/s/17o44aerf71zfwg/hr.svg?dl=0 (I've added an ID by hand for each municipality)
Basically, I can't get the two maps to zoom together nicely

Comment: Also, using topoJSON, I'll have an easier access to the data, so it will be easier and cleaner to create tooltips for each municipality.

Comment: Ah, that could be more challenging. It appears that you linked to the same document each time above (or am I really blind?).  Do both SVGs use the same projection?  If not, you'll not be able to align them when zooming without a lot of extra work. If you can share the second SVG I could dig in a bit more.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't realize that it's the same link. Here are all three of them:
Regions: https://www.dropbox.com/s/07wuv1myjbnwdtf/hr.json?dl=0 https://www.dropbox.com/s/17o44aerf71zfwg/hr.svg?dl=0
Municipalities: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vtvaod1jamlnc0d/municipalities.svg?dl=0